# iOS: I would like clicking on a tab bar item to always point to the original URL

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitabbar

I have an app with 4 tabs.

One of these tabs is a UIWebView. It starts at a particular URL. I would like to have it so that after navigating around in this webview through clicking on links and all that, when you click on the tab item again it reloads the original URL. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In the `viewWillAppear` method of the view controller that contains the UIWebView, always have it set the URL to the original.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@”http://www.google.com”];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

**Edit** Re: Your comments:

```
//Where you set the UITabBarDelegate (maybe in AppDelegate)
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
   if (item == webViewItem) {
      //Navigating to the web view or already showing it
      [webViewController reloadWebView]
   } else if (webViewNeedsReloading) {
      //Navigating to some other view
      [webViewController reloadWebView]
   }
}
```

I only put the checks in because I'm an optimizing fiend and hate running code unnecessarily. That being said, I'm sure just doing:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
   [webViewController reloadWebView]
}
```

would be fine and have no perceivable impact on performance.

Comment: This only works when I select another tab and then go back to it, how could I make it fire when I'm re-clicking on a tab that's already selected?

Comment: Also another question: When I reload the original URL this way, what was open in the UIWebView flashes quickly before reverting back to the original URL. How can I hide this from the user?

Comment: First: Use the `UITabBarDelegate` method `tabBar:didSelectItem:` to catch the selection and call a method on that view controller directly to do the reload.

Comment: Second: I would probably use the 'tabBar:didSelectItem:' and reload the webview as soon as the user navigates to some other tab so it will be ready when they go back again. The loading is done in the background, so doing this shouldn't hang your main thread.

Comment: What if the user wants to return to the "main menu" so to speak while they're still in the same tab?

Comment: Sorry, must not have explained my first comment well enough. Using the `tabBar:didSelectItem:` (which will be called even if the tab is already selected) method, have an if statement compare the `UITabBarItem` argument with the `UITabBarItem` that goes to the view controller with the `UIWebView`. If it is the same, call some method on that view controller that reloads the webview.